# JSP syntax for an empty custom tag?

Tags: java, jsp, tags

What is the proper way of creating an empty custom tag in JSP?

Is should have a prefix and suffix. An example would be TWONG prefix and GLOOP as suffix. Which choices are valid?

```
a) <TWONG:GLOOP/>
b) <GLOOP:TWONG/>
c) <TWONG:GLOOP><TWONG:GLOOP/>
d) <GLOOP:TWONG><GLOOP:TWONG/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search of "Empty custom tag in JSP" revealed [zetcode.com: Custom JSP tags](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/jeetutorials/customjsptags/).

Their first code sample has the following in it:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="d" uri="http://zetcode.com/tlds/date" %>

<html>
...
    <body>
        <h2>Date</h2>
        <b>Today's Date: </b> <d:DateTag />
    </body>
```

The relevant items I see in there are `taglib prefix="d"` and `<d:DateTag />`.

Since `d` is the prefix, I would assume the option of `<PREFIX:SUFFIX/>` is correct.

So, option a. `<TWONG:GLOOP/>`